# Model to query all feature classes in geodatabase by selecting by attribute?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, spatial-database, query

I have a geodatabase that has 60+ feature classes that each contain records for 60+ locations.  I need to export all records from each feature class for a specific location.  In each FC there is a common attribute that identifies each location (i.e. instln_id).  I would like to do this in ModelBuilder but have not had any luck with iterating feature classes or workspaces and selecting by attributes.  Basically I want to scan through every feature class for records with a specific attribute and export records to new feature classes.  Does anyone have any ideas or examples of something you've done that is similar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like what you need to do is use the `Iterator` functionality in Modelbuilder.

[Iterate Feature Classes (Modelbuilder)](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Iterate_Feature_Classes/00400000000r000000/)

I created a quick model that looks as follows:

[image: Iterate feature class model]

As you can see, the parameters of the `Select` query, include an Expression to Select by "instln_id" = 'Local'.  You would just change the value to your desired location.

The selection will then be saved out to a new feature class.  In this case, the **Output** feature class uses the `Name` of the **Input** Feature Class, and appends `Local` to it.  This of course, can be modified as necessary.

This type of iterator should work not only on a geodatabase, but any type of workspace.  There is an option to have it operate recursively, so you could start at a top level directory, and it will cycle through any subfolders.

As I said, this is basic, so you could add additional filters to only search specific feature classes within your GDB, whether based on name, or feature type, etc.